# How to Call Google Cloud Function From the Command Line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How do I call my Google Cloud function from the command line? I created a simple Hello World function, that works when I use a curl command to call it, but using the `gcloud functions call hello-world` command tells me that the function does not exist.

```
% gcp functions list
NAME         STATE   TRIGGER       REGION       ENVIRONMENT
hello-world  ACTIVE  HTTP Trigger  us-central1  2nd gen

% gcp functions call hello-world
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) ResponseError: status=[404], code=[Ok], message=[Function hello-world in region us-central1 in project test-project does not exist]
```

I thought maybe something was mismatched with the zone, so I set my default region and zone using the following command, but still no luck.

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
   --metadata google-compute-default-region=us-central1,google-compute-default-zone=us-central1-a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/call#--gen2), Cloud Functions uses the First generation environment if you did not use the `--gen2` **Flag**. You can try this below command:

`gcloud functions call hello-world --region us-central1 --gen2`

Sample Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to have this flag set by default?

Comment: Just found it for anyone looking `gcloud config set functions/gen2 true`